# Hello, I want to extract a website and store the data in excel file

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, data-mining

I want to extract a website and store the data in excel file
website :- https://www.mygov.in/corona-data/covid19-statewise-status

in this website are store a state wise covid-19 data 
i want to there data extract in excel file using python

remember i want only state wise data in there website table format

Comment: You need to provide some code to get an answer. We are not here to program for you.
That said the easiest way to grab data from a website would be curl. If you need more power you might try scrapy, and if you need something with ajax and higher level scraping you can use selenium.

Comment: Try openpyxl, https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you: (Corona Virus (COVID-19) cases in India python program) :

```
import urllib.request
import os
import time
while(True):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve ("https://www.mohfw.gov.in/", "webpage.html")
    o=open('webpage.html',"r")
    print("\n***********************************COVID-19 CASES IN INDIA********************************")
    print("* STATE\t\t\t\t CONFIRMED CASES\t CURED\t\t\tDEATH    *")
    states=["Andaman and Nicobar Islands","Andhra Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Chandigarh","Chhattisgarh","Delhi","Goa","Gujarat","Haryana","Himachal Pradesh","Jammu and Kashmir","Jharkhand","Karnataka","Kerala","Ladakh","Madhya Pradesh","Maharashtra","Manipur","Mizoram","Odisha","Puducherry","Punjab","Rajasthan","Tamil Nadu","Telengana","Uttarakhand","Uttar Pradesh","West Bengal","Total"]        
    j=0
    c=0
    for i in o:
        s=str(i)
        if(c!=0):
            temp=''
            for p in s:
                if p in '0123456789':
                    temp+=p
            if(len(temp)==0):
                continue
            print(temp,end='')
            c+=1
            if(c==4):
                c=0
                for space in range(len(temp),9):
                    print(" ",end='')
                print("*")
                continue
            for space in range(len(temp),23):
                print(" ",end='')
            continue
        if(j>30):
            break                    
        if(states[j] in s):
            print("*",end=' ')
            print(states[j],end="")
            for space in range(len(states[j]),32):
                print("",end=' ')
            c=1
            j+=1
            continue
    print("******************************************************************************************")
    o.close()
    os.remove("webpage.html")
    print("UPDATING IN 6 MINUTES...")
    time.sleep(600)
```

OUTPUT:
[image]